# Multiple Headers in recycleview not working - why so?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, stickyrecycleview

I want to create recycleview with multiple headers , the first header is working perfectly fine but the rest of the headers are not working as expected. This is my first time with recycleview headers . And also i would like to know is this the proper way of doing it.

Here is my Adapter.

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private List<ItemObject> itemObjects;
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter( Context context , List<ItemObject> itemObjects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.itemObjects = itemObjects;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false);
            return new HeaderViewHolder(layoutView);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(layoutView , context);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("No match for " + viewType + ".");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemObject mObject = itemObjects.get(position);
        if(holder instanceof HeaderViewHolder){
            ((HeaderViewHolder) holder).headerTitle.setText(mObject.getContents());
        }else if(holder instanceof ItemViewHolder){
            ((ItemViewHolder) holder).itemContent.setText(mObject.getContents());
        }
    }
    private ItemObject getItem(int position) {
        return itemObjects.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemObjects.size();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }
}
```

and here is my method in main activity.

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this , getDataSource());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

```
   private List <ItemObject> getDataSource(){
  List<ItemObject> list1 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();

        list1.add(new ItemObject("First Header",true));
        list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));


        List <ItemObject> list2 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
        list2.add(new ItemObject("Second Header",true));
        list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));


        List <ItemObject> list3 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
        list3.add(new ItemObject("Third Header",true));
        list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position"));
        list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position"));

        List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list2);
        finalList.addAll(list3);

        return finalList;
[![I get first header 2 times][1]][1]
}
```

and here is my item object class.

```
public class ItemObject {
    private String contents;
    boolean isHeader ;


    public ItemObject(String contents, boolean isHeader) {
        this.contents = contents;
        this.isHeader = isHeader;
    }

    public ItemObject(String contents) {

        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public boolean isHeader() {
        return isHeader;
    }
}
```

I get first header 2 times like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiaSX.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list2);
        finalList.addAll(list3);`

With `List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
        finalList.addAll(list1);
        finalList.addAll(list2);
        finalList.addAll(list3)`

you are adding the first header two times here

```
List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>(list1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List.addAll()` just concatenates the items of the `List` passed as parameter to `finalList`. i.e. you end up with a `List` with 9 items. That's why your condition `position == 0` only works for your first header.

One possible (simple) solution will be to modify your `ItemObject` to have a flag indicating that a given item is a header (notice this is the second parameter of the constructor, `true` being is a header, `false` otherwise).

```
private List <ItemObject> getDataSource(){
    List<ItemObject> list1 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();

    list1.add(new ItemObject("First Header", true));
    list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position", false));
    list1.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position", false));

    List <ItemObject> list2 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
    list2.add(new ItemObject("Second Header", true));
    list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position", false));
    list2.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position", false));

    List <ItemObject> list3 = new ArrayList <ItemObject>();
    list3.add(new ItemObject("Third Header", true));
    list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the first position", false));
    list3.add(new ItemObject("This is the item content in the second position", false));

    List <ItemObject> finalList = new ArrayList <ItemObject>(list1);
    finalList.addAll(list1);
    finalList.addAll(list2);
    finalList.addAll(list3);

    return finalList;
}
```

And then your condition in the adapter will be something similar to this:

```
private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    ItemObject mObject = itemObjects.get(position);
    return mObject.isHeader();
}
```

Comment: I have tried your solution it works, i have updated my code but i get first list 2 times like this https://imgur.com/a/2YZ8DxM